# How to test Java JAR in Android?

Tags: java, android, junit, junit4, junit3

I have Java JAR with JUnit4 tests, which is being used by an Android application. I have received request to test the JAR within Android. Is it possible ? As Android has there own test runners with JUnit3. Do I have to use what is supported by Android ? Or Is it possible to execute JUnit4 tests in Android using emulator ?